# Can neither read nor format USB

Tags: format

I want to format my old USB from unknown filesystem to nstf to make it a W7 boot USB. But after using GParted to format it, it suddenly stopped working, so I tried to repair it.

This is what I've done

```
X@Y:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

```
X@Y:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/tmp/xxx bs=512 count=1
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': No medium found
```

```
X@Y:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdb unit s print
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? r                                                           
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? t                                                           
parted: invalid token: t
Retry/Cancel? r                                                           
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? r                                                           
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? r                                                           
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? r                                                           
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? r                                                           
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? r                                                           
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found
Retry/Cancel? c
```

```
X@Y:~$ sudo fdisk -l

blah blah blah...

Disk /dev/sdb: 59,6 GiB, 63963136000 bytes, 124928000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Also, it won't stop flashing. Is it dead?

Edit 1: It stopped flashing and the light is off after I restart

Comment: what are you trying to do here`sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/tmp/xxx bs=512 count=1`?

Comment: There was a solution that told me to do that

Comment: It should have been `if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`

Comment: It still output such thing: `dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': No medium found`

Comment: Pls run `sudo lsblk -f` to get the actual mount device name